# What are the recommended tools (other than LaTex) for academicians and professionals?

Tags: best-practices

I am not sure if this sort of question is allowed or not, but I thought it was better to try than not. The reason I am asking this here is because I want the answer from the sort of person who uses LaTex. So I couldn't really ask this elsewhere could I?

So I discovered LaTex about 3 or 4 months back and now I feel like I could never use MS Word again for anything (especially if its longer than 2 pages). I only wish I hadn't discovered it so late! I came across 'git' recently and am considering learning to use it as I don't use any version control system atm! And that's got me thinking - if I didn't know about something as amazing as LaTex then are there other such tools out there that I am missing out on.

So I just want to ask you lot if there is something that you use in your academic/professional life that you feel you can't live without - something that you think a graduate or PhD student would find worth investing in.

Comment: I think this question is highly opinion-based and thus hard to answer (if ever). Everybody equals different things as useful. And a computer scientist needs other things than a historian.

Comment: I think if anywhere this would go on Academia-StackExchange, but even then likely 'too broad' or 'opinion based'.

Comment: Well, there used to be this thing called a "slide rule..." ;^)

Comment: @Johannes_B -- And, sadly, most historians don't consider LaTeX indispensable, which makes journal submissions an annoying pain...

Comment: I agree that its opinion based, but its those opinions that I want to hear so I can make my own judgement based on them. Do opinions not have any value? Also when those opinions get upvoted - I imagine you'd end up with more or less a 'list of useful tools for a typical LaTeX user' - I am curious to see what that would look like - aren't you? And I am sure it'd be useful for the latex community (especially those new to such tools). I'd also argue that most of the answers on this forum are opinion based. But I suppose if the forum rules say so, I'll have to try someplace else.

Comment: Are you asking what tools are useful in conjunction with (La)TeX? If that's the case, you need to clarify it in your question. Otherwise the question is too broad for the site topic.

Comment: No I wasn't - just want to know what tools (whether used in conjunction with Latex or not) form the arsenal of a LATEX USER. I understand that there might be some answers that only apply to a minority but the upvoted answers would surely be those tools that are common to most LaTex users.